# Ensure that object has every enum value as a key (Typescript)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want typescript to throw error when object does not have every enum value as a key. Is it possible?

```js
type EnumMap<T> = { ??? }

enum Colors {
    Red = 'Red',
    Blue = 'Blue'
}

const obj1: EnumMap<Colors> = {
  [Colors.Red]: 'roses',
  [Colors.Blue]: 'violets'
} // works fine

const obj2: EnumMap<Colors> = {
  [Colors.Red]: 'roses'
} // should throw error since Colors.Blue is not among obj2 keys
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `Record` helper type (read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt)) like that

```
type EnumMap<T extends string> = Record<T, string>
```

which is an equivalent of

```
type EnumMap<T extends string> = { [key in T]: string}
```

[image]